# Tempusdominus update event not firing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker to select a date for an appointment, when I initialize the datepicker I set the enabled dates for the current month, and I want to catch the update event that is supposed to be fired when the user clicks on the next button (i.e. changes month)

Here's the JSP bit:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="fechaCita" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#fechaCita"/>
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#fechaCita" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js part:

```
$('#fechaCita').datetimepicker({
    format : 'DD/MM/YYYY', // Solo se mostrará la fecha
    enabledDates : enabledDates,
    useCurrent : false,
    locale : 'es',
    icons : {
        date : "fa fa-calendar",
        up : "fa fa-caret-up",
        down : "fa fa-caret-down",
        previous : "fa fa-caret-left",
        next : "fa fa-caret-right",
        today : "fa fa-today",
        clear : "fa fa-clear",
        close : "fa fa-close"
    }

});

$("#fechaCita").on("update.datetimepicker", function(e) {
        console.log('Update ');
});
```

When I click on the next button, nothing is written to the console...

I'm using Tempusdominus 5.0.1, Bootstrap, jQuery 3.4.1, moment 2.24.0 and popper 1.14.3